# nginx: Redirect special characters like "%23" in URL to "#"

Tags: nginx, character-encoding, special-characters, redirect

My nginx site has a few bad links pointing to it like this:

- `/some-page%23some-part`
- `/some-page&quot;&gt;`

This is causing 404's and Google Webmaster Tools is complaining too.

The URL `/some-page#some-part` *does* get processed properly and works.

How can I get nginx to redirect the `%23` in a URL to `#`?  What about the `&quot;&gt;` junk?

The links out there cannot be changed, so I'm looking to 301 redirect them myself.

Thanks!

*Edit: thanks to Deadooshka for the help.  My working solution, `rewrite ^(.*)\#(.*)$ /$1#$2 redirect;`, is discussed within his answer's comment thread.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not tested. I'm not sure which symbols get the pattern.

```
rewrite ^/([^\#]+)\#([^\#]+)$ /$1#$2 redirect;
rewrite '^/([^\&]+)\&quot\;\&gt\;$' /$1 redirect;
```

Comment: Thanks, but no dice.  Seems that `\%23` isn't going to do it for some reason.  Even this simple line does nothing:  `rewrite ^/.*\%23.*$ / redirect;`  Any other ideas?

Comment: +1, however, since `rewrite '^/([^\&]+)\&quot\;\&gt\;$' /$1 redirect;` seems to work perfectly!

Should have made this into two different questions I suppose.  Anyway, if one of us can get %23 then I'll post it up and give you the correct answer to edit in.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Berto did you try to place `\#` instead of `\%23` in the pattern? The server is usually decodes the path before the rewrite processing.

Comment: Wondering if this has anything to do with what I need:  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSetMiscModule#set_unescape_uri  from  http://serverfault.com/questions/551751/how-to-explicitly-apply-percent-escapes-to-a-url-in-nginx

Comment: The first `rewrite` looks like a loop, but the browser must not send the hash part of URL. Consider to remove the hash part from redirected URL, as we can not rely on the behavior of clients.

Comment: Allright!!!  `rewrite ^(.*)\#(.*)$ /$1#$2 redirect;` worked!  However, is that going to add nginx processing time to *any* URL that has a `#` in it?  Or will the server not see that extra data the next time once they're properly formatted?  Is my regex the best idea?  Once we find something you like and you fix your main answer, I'll give you the accepted answer.

Comment: The hash component is just a browser stuff. But not all clients comply with the HTTP protocol, that may cause an infinite loop. So i think the redirected url must not contain the hash part. `rewrite ^/([^\#]+)\# /$1 redirect;`

Comment: My *BELIEF* is that when nginx sees `%23`, it doesn't interpret that as a "browser-based" `#`, and processes the whole thing.  So I think you still need to redirect the whole thing back to the browser if you want to keep the part that was *supposed* to be after the `#`.  Anyway, I'm marking this as the correct answer, since anyone else searching for this should be able to find the right stuff in this thread.